# PC will not post out of the blue

Tags: boot, motherboard

Today I changed my power strip with one with more slots, so naturally I turned everything off, plugged the cords to the new power strip and tried to boot my system.

Alas, the motherboard is giving me an error with 2 beeps followed by 4 beeps and there is no video output to the monitor. The system is not booting at all, but all fans seem to work fine.

I've encountered this in the past and the issue was magically fixed on its own after a reboot or two, but now the problem persists.

I have tried re-seating CPU, GPU and RAM, I also removed the CMOS battery, drained the leftover power and put it back in but without any luck.

What is happening here and how do I fix it?

Specs:

- Motherboard: Gigabyte Aorus Gaming 5 x470 (BIOS v. F50)
- CPU: AMD Ryzen 1700x
- RAM: Hyper-X Predator 3GHz 16GB
- GPU: Sapphire RX 580 8GB Nitro+
- PSU:
  Corsair RM 750 80+ Gold

Comment: Was there some sort of power surge?  From OFF, try starting in BIOS.  Nominally F1 but check your own documentation

Comment: @John no power surge because I've got a power strip that prevents that. I just switched it off. The keyboard is not receiving any power in order to try and mash "delete" to enter BIOS. there is no video output at all, not even the BIOS screen.

Comment: That wold indicate the power supply has gone defective.

Comment: Have you tried using the older power strip (back to normal), and removing all other items around besides the PC & Monitor (?).

Comment: Since you have gone through all you have, try and re-seat the 8-pin ATX 12V power connector and 24 line ATX power to the motherboard.

Comment: @vssher just tried those as well but to no avail unfortunately.

Comment: @John i don't have a spare one to test this, any chance you'd know how to make sure without buying a new one ?

Comment: @John additionally would a bad PSU explain the POST codes? (the beeps)

Comment: If you have or can borrow a voltmeter, you can try checking the output values. You would need documentation for the power supply. A bad PSU (output on one leg failed) could explain the beeps

Comment: @John I noticed my keyboard is not getting any power, is it at all possible that it doesn't post because it does not detect a keyboard?

Comment: Some computers will beep if no keyboard. But if is connected why no power (except faulty power)

Comment: @John my only guess would be because of fast startup or faulty psu

Comment: Fast Startup does not normally cause these issues. All our client computers have Fast Start enabled

Comment: contact Gigabyte ans ask them bout the meaning of that beep code, the manual only says: `The system reports system startup status by issuing a beep code. One single short beep will be heard if no problem is detected at system startup.`

Comment: @John turns out it's not the PSU, I checked it on another pc and it worked fine. Any other guesses? Starting to look suspiciously like a defective MOBO to me.

Comment: If the PSU is fine, then likely now the Motherboard is the issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems more like letting you know what happened than an actual answer but after some days of technical "examination" and troubleshooting it turned out that my Motherboard's North Bridge chip was the culprit.

Got a new Motherboard and all seems fine now.